# Populate combobox with number of days according to month and year

Tags: c#, datetime, combobox

My month and year is also from a combobox. I'm having trouble with the year combobox. i already convert the value of both month and year to int. the month I don't have a problem. but the year is having issue

> "Year must be between 1 and 9999. Parameter name: year"

and I tried to check the value of the converted int of the year and convert it again to other string and pass it to a label so i can see if the value is 0 but it's not. it says 2016. but there's still that error. (sorry for my English).

```
int monthhh = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox_Month.GetItemText(comboBox_Month.SelectedItem), "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;    
int yearrr;   
int.TryParse(comboBox_Year.GetItemText(comboBox_Year.SelectedItem), out yearrr);    
int[] days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearrr, monthhh)).ToArray();    
comboBox_Day.DataSource = days;
```

I've also done this code:

```
int yearrr = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_Year.SelectedValue);
```

the same problem occurs.

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: on the int[] days line.. @SonerGönül

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what is the value of `comboBox_Year.SelectedItem` exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül sorry it's 0.. i've tried this code int.TryParse(comboBox_Year.GetItemText(comboBox_Year.SelectedItem), out yearrr); but it still give me a 0 value but when i pass it to a string and put it on a label it's not 0.. sorry i've been trying so many things earlier and it's not working..

Comment: If is `comboBox_Year.SelectedValue` is _already_ `0`, isn't it too normal to get `0` when you parse it to `int`?

Comment: but how do i convert the comboxbox to an int value.. how do i convert the string '2016' from a combobox to int.. i used             int yearrr = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox_Year.SelectedValue); but it gives me 0 int value.. @SonerGönül